# How can we prove that a positive-frequency wave and its time-derivative cannot both have compact support in space?

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, asymptotics, smooth-functions

Consider a complex-valued function of the form
$$
\newcommand{\bfx}{\mathbf{x}}
\newcommand{\bfk}{\mathbf{k}}
f(t,\bfx)=\int d^Nk\ g(\bfk)\exp\big(-i\omega(\bfk)t-i\bfk\cdot\bfx\big)
\tag{1}
$$
where boldface denotes a list of $N$ real variables, the dot-product is defined as usual, and
$$
\omega(\bfk)\equiv \sqrt{\strut{}1+\bfk\cdot\bfk}.
\tag{2}
$$
(I'm calling this a "wave," but notice the constant term under the square root.) Suppose that $f(0,\bfx)$ is nonzero at least for some $\bfx$. Can we choose $g(\bfk)$ so that $f(t,\bfx)$ and $df(t,\bfx)/dt$ both have compact support in $\bfx$ at $t=0$?

The answer must be no, because otherwise I could use the [Paley-Wiener theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paley%E2%80%93Wiener_theorem) to construct a contradiction to the [Reeh-Schlieder theorem](https://arxiv.org/abs/1803.04993). But that's a very indirect argument that uses relativistic quantum field theory, which surely isn't necessary for the simple question I'm asking here! How can we prove more directly that no such $g(\bfk)$ exists?

Comment: I am trying to understand the same issue but for more general functions, since recently I found the paper [Finite Time Differential Equations](https://sci-hub.se/10.1109/CDC.1985.268832) I am trying to figure out if their findings can be extended to more than one dimensions (unsuccessfully so far). Maybe it could help you.

Comment: I am not fully sure about this, but I think it is possible to adjust the function shown in [this answer to a question I made](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4333286/909869) to be a counter-example to your question.

Comment: @Joako Thank you for the comment! I don't know how to adjust that example to construct a counter-example, though. If we omit the "$1$" term under the square root in my equation (2), then any function of the form $f(kx-ct)$ with compact support at $t=0$ would be a counter-example with $N=1$. It's that pesky "$1$" term under the square root that makes things difficult.

Comment: @Joako By the way, the function $E(x,y,z,t)=f(k_xx-ct, k_yy-ct, k_zz-ct)$ shown in that example doesn't satisfy the usual wave equation. Not sure what the author of that answer meant.

Comment: If I remember I do checked on Wolfram-Alpha at least it do works in two dimensions (only variables $x$ and $t$ considered), but knowing myself I probably checked it also on 2D $(x,\ y,\ t)$... also the traveling way $f(kx-ct)$ is a classic solution for the wave equation in 1D so it should be right: maybe the value of $k$ is not well calculated? (I remember having problem with it - as you could see on the comments)

Comment: with unitary constants I do check it in 1 spatial dimension [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=factor+D%5Be%5E%28-1%2F%281-%28x-t%29%5E2%29%29%2C%7Bx%2C2%7D%5D-D%5Be%5E%28-1%2F%281-%28x-t%29%5E2%29%29%2C%7Bt%2C2%7D%5D), but you are right, it looks it fails for more dimensions, I don't know why

Comment: @Joako In case you're interested, here's a relatively easy way to prove that the version with $\geq 2$ dimensions doesn't satisfy the wave equation. In $N$-dimensional space, the usual wave equation with $c=1$ is 
$$
 \partial_t^2E(t,x_1,...,x_N)
 =(\partial_1^2+\cdots+\partial_N^2)E(t,x_1,...,x_N)
$$ with $\partial_n\equiv \partial/\partial x_n$. Continued...

Comment: @Joako Now let $f(x_1,...,x_N)$ be any smooth function, and suppose 
$$
 E(t,x_1,...,x_N)=f(x_1-t,x_2-t,...,x_N-t).
$$
 Any such function $E(t,x_1,...,x_N)$ satisfies 
$$
 \partial_t^2 E = (\partial_1+\partial_2+\cdots+\partial_N)^2 E.
$$
 If $E$ also satisfies the wave equation, then this immediately implies 
$$
 \sum_{j\neq k} \partial_j\partial_k E = 0.
$$
 By inspection, the example described in the other answer doesn't satisfy this when $N\geq 2$, not even when $t=0$.

Comment: @ChiralAnonaly I think your last hypothesis is not right (if I understood properly: [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=factor+D%5Bcos%28x%2Fsqrt%282%29%2By%2Fsqrt%282%29-t%29%2C%7Bx%2C2%7D%5D%2BD%5Bcos%28x%2Fsqrt%282%29%2By%2Fsqrt%282%29-t%29%2C%7By%2C2%7D%5D-D%5Bcos%28x%2Fsqrt%282%29%2By%2Fsqrt%282%29-t%29%2C%7Bt%2C2%7D%5D&lang=es) is an example of a function in $R^{2+1}$ that fulfill the wave equation, (...)

Comment: (...) but the [sum of their crossed-derivatives is not zero](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=factor+D%5BD%5Bcos%28x%2Fsqrt%282%29%2By%2Fsqrt%282%29-t%29%2Cx%5D%2Cy%5D%2BD%5BD%5Bcos%28x%2Fsqrt%282%29%2By%2Fsqrt%282%29-t%29%2Cx%5D%2Ct%5D%2BD%5BD%5Bcos%28x%2Fsqrt%282%29%2By%2Fsqrt%282%29-t%29%2Cy%5D%2Ct%5D&lang=es)

Comment: @Joako Good example! The other answer didn't specify the values of the coefficients $k_x,k_y,k_z$, so for simplicity I set them all equal to $1$. That choice was essential in my proof. Your example has the form $E(t,x,y)=f(k_xx- t,k_yy- t)$ with $k_x=k_y\neq 1$, and it shows that my proof really does rely on the simplification $k_x=k_y=1$. Your example doesn't have compact support along the $x-y$ direction, because it's independent of that combination of coordinates, but it at least exposes an important limitation of my proof.

Comment: it is just a simple plane wave as example for the cross-derivatives sum, not for the compact-support function. The classic plane wave is $\exp(i\vec{k}\vec{x}-ict)$ such as $|\vec{k}|=1$, so the components of vector $\vec{k}$ only will be unitary on one dimension