# Does the Laplace's equation $\nabla^2 u=0$ could have smooth compact-supported solutions $\in C_c^\infty$? Any example?

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, partial-differential-equations, special-functions, harmonic-functions

**Does the Laplace's equation $\nabla^2 u=0$  could have smooth compact-supported solutions $\in C_c^\infty$? Any example?**

In [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4333286/909869) an user named @NinadMunshi explain that the following function $f:\Bbb{R}^3\to\Bbb{R}$

$$f(x,y,z) = \begin{cases}\exp\left[\frac{-1}{R^2-x^2-y^2-z^2}\right] & x^2+y^2+z^2 < R^2 \\ 0 & x^2+y^2+z^2 \geq R^2\end{cases}$$

Then for $k\in\Bbb{R}^3$ with $|k|=1$, we have that

$$E_i(x,y,z,t) = f(x-ck_xt,y-ck_yt, z-ck_zt)$$

satisfies the wave equation $\frac{1}{c^2}\frac{\partial^2}{\partial t^2}E=\nabla^2 E$.

I would like to know if its possible also for the [Laplace's Equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace%27s_equation) $\nabla^2 u = 0$ to stand [smooth bump-like solutions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bump_function) $\in C_c^\infty$, at least in one coordinate.

I believe that if the function is complex-valued $u(\vec{x}) \in \mathbb{C}$ then no [harmonic solution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_function) could be compact-supported due the [Liouville's theorem (complex analysis)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville%27s_theorem_(complex_analysis)), at least if is not defined piecewise as the example for the wave equation, but I don't have any intuition of what would happen if the function is real-valued.

Hope you can answer giving a basic example: piecewise solution are allowed, but must be solving the differential equation in the whole domain and not only where the non-zero piecewise section is defined, so it behave as a properly solution to the Laplace's equation which has a [smooth bump function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bump_function) behavior (as it does the example for the wave equation).

---

**Motivation**

Recently I learned that a scalar 2nd order ordinary differential equation (ODE) require to have a point in time where is locally non-Lipschitz in order to been able of having solution with a finite extinction time (details [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4452203/909869), reference on this [paper](https://doi.org/10.1109/CDC.1985.268832)), which brakes uniqueness of solutions.

Since this will apply for scalar smooth bump functions, I would like to know why this singular point is not required on PDEs for having a smooth-bump behavior on any coordinate as is shown for the wave equation example, so I would like to know how the arise for the Laplace's equation, or if instead they aren't possible.

Comment: The answer is no: solutions of Laplace’s equation are analytic, and no nonzero, smooth, compactly supported function $u$ can be analytic at the boundary of its support. This is because all derivatives must be zero outside the support of $u$, and thus by continuity, all derivatives of $u$ are zero on the boundary of the support, which means the Taylor expansion of $u$ on the boundary of its support is identically zero. If $u$ was analytic there, then $u$ would be zero on an open ball containing some piece of its support, which is impossible.

Comment: Have a look at the maximum principle for Laplace’s equation.

Comment: @Aruralreader Thanks for commenting. I have reviewed in Wikipedia the [Maximum Principle](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_principle) for the Laplace's equation, but how is described there, I don't understand Why it not apply also for the wave equation?.. maybe is that the case and the example I give is mistaken? (I made it work in $\mathbb{R}^{1+1}$, but I cannot make it work for $\mathbb{R}^{2+1}$). Hope you can elaborate into this on an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer is just for closing this question, since it was given on the comments by @Aruralreader:

Due the [Maximum principle](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_principle) apply for the Laplace equation, it implies that the maximum of the function must happen on the "boundaries", so if the solution is a [smooth-bump function](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bump_function) it will imply that the maximum is on the edges were the function value is zero, so the only possible solution fulfilling both situations is the zero function.