# Bump function on the plane

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, smooth-functions

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ be defined as $$f(x) =
\begin{cases}
e^{\frac{1}{x^2-1}}, & \text{if }|x|<1 \\
0, & \text{if }|x|\geq 1.
\end{cases}$$ It is not difficult to check that $f\in C^1(\mathbb{R})$ with $f(x)=0$ if $|x|>1$ and $f(x)>0$ if $|x|\leq 1$. Now I'd like to construct the similar function on the plane. Let $f:\mathbb{R}^2\to \mathbb{R}$ be defined as $$f(x,y) =
\begin{cases}
e^{\frac{1}{x^2+y^2-1}}, & \text{if } x^2+y^2<1 \\
0, & \text{if }x^2+y^2\geq 1.
\end{cases}$$
I want to prove that $f\in C^1(\mathbb{R}^2; \mathbb{R})$, i.e., partial derivatives of $f$ exists and continuous. It is not difficult to verify that $$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x,y) =
\begin{cases}
-\frac{2x e^{\frac{1}{x^2+y^2-1}}}{(x^2+y^2-1)^2}, & \text{if } x^2+y^2<1 \\
0, & \text{if }x^2+y^2\geq 1.
\end{cases}$$
It shows that $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ exists everywhere on $\mathbb{R}^2$.
But what about continuity of $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$?

From the definition of $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ it follows that it is continuous on $\{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2: x^2+y^2<1\}\cup \{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2: x^2+y^2>1\}$. But is it continuous on the boundary? I mean suppose that $(x_0,y_0)\in \mathbb{R}^2$ such that $x_0^2+y_0^2=1$. How to show that $$\lim_{(x,y)\to (x_0,y_0)}\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x,y)=0.$$

I have some issues to show this rigorously.
Can anyone show the proof please?

Comment: There seems to be a mistake in your derivative, I think it should be something like $-\frac{2xe^{\frac1{x^2+y^2-1}}}{(x^2+y^2-1)^2}$, at least the exp should have a $y^2$ extra. I did not check the rest of this derivative. I think then you will find why things go wrong?

Comment: @student91, thank you for your remark! I had the right answer on the paper but made a typo when typing. No it still unclear how to to compute that limit.

Comment: No need to calulate the derivatives! If $\varphi:\mathbb R\to \mathbb R$ is ($n$-times) continuously differentiable then so is $f:\mathbb R^2\to\mathbb R$, $(x,y)\mapsto \varphi(x^2+y^2)$.

Comment: @Jochen, indeed, it is much easier than I thought! So it follows basically from the fact that composition of smooth functions is smooth, right?

Comment: Yes, of course.

Comment: @Jochen, just a small correction: I guess you meant $f:\mathbb{R}^2\to \mathbb{R}$, $(x,y)\mapsto f(\sqrt{x^2+y^2})$

Comment: This depends on the definition of $\varphi$. It is better to avoid the non-differentiable square root.

Comment: Express $f$ and $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}, \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}$ in polar coordinates. Note that all three go to $0$ as $r\to 1$. As $r$ is continuous and the boundary is $r = 1$, you cannot approach the boundary without $r \to 1$.

Comment: In [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4333286/909869) to a question I did an user gives a beautiful example plot of the function you are exploring.